# a class with all static methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python Class with all methods being static,

```
class SomeClass:

    @staticmethod
    def somemethod(...):
       pass

    @staticmethod
    def somemethod2(...):
       pass

    @staticmethod
    def somemethod3(...):
       pass
```

Is it the right way to do so?

Comment: Of course you can refactor this to be just functions. But that's not critical.

Comment: This should scream "I should just be a module"

Comment: Static methods aren't very common in Python, and a Python class that only has static methods seems rather strange to me - Python isn't Java, and slavishly copying Java patterns in Python tends to produce ugly, bloated code. Why not just make them into normal functions defined at the module level? You can put them into their own module to group them together.

Comment: @PM2Ring it may increase the number of modules, each with just two or three functions

Comment: @GrizzledSquirrel you've got 2 possible outcomes. Either you accept that this should really be a module - or at least, not a class, or we'd close this as "primarily opinion-based" - "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: The use of a class is only somewhat appropriate whenever you'd pass `SomeClass` as an *argument* somewhere, or whenever you use inheritance to fill in methods with default implementations, or so on.

Comment: @GrizzledSquirrel Ultimately, how you structure your code is your decision; my previous comment was just to let you know common Python practice. There is little to be gained in wrapping a bunch of functions that aren't methods into a class, you just make it a little more tedious to call them. Consider: the standard `math` module bundles a bunch of unrelated functions into a module, it doesn't wrap the trig & inverse trig functions into one class, the exponential and logarithmic functions into another, etc.

Comment: thats an interesting point! Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If all the methods are static, you DON'T need a class.

*(Same if you have a class with only an **init** and 1 method)*

## someclass.py

```
class SomeClass:

    @staticmethod
    def somemethod(...):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def somemethod2(...):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def somemethod3(...):
        pass
```

Then you use it mostly like:

```
from someclass import SomeClass
some_class = SomeClass()
some_class.somemethod()
....
```

## I always refactor such class into simple methods

## someclass.py

```
def somemethod(...):
    pass

def somemethod2(...):
    pass

def somemethod3(...):
    pass
```

then I use it this way:

```
import someclass
someclass.somemethod()
...
```

Isn't this cleaner and simpler?

## Extra info

```
class SomeClass:

    foo = 1

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        self.foo = 2

    @staticmethod
    def somemethod():
        # no access to self nor cls but can read foo via SomeClass.foo (1)
        foo = SomeClass.foo
        SomeClass.someclassmethod()
        ...

    @classmethod
    def someclassmethod(cls, ...):
        # access to cls, cls.foo (always 1), no access to bar
        foo = cls.foo
        ...

    def someinstancemethod(self, ...):
        # access to self, self.bar, self.foo (2 instead of 1 because of init)
        foo = self.foo
        bar = self.bar
        self.somemethod()
        self.someclassmethod()
        ...
```

Comment: This is correct, only quibble is because the OP's class has only static methods, you wouldn't ever instantiate it; they would just use `SomeClass.somemethod()`.

Comment: Agreed, but most of the time I see code using static methods via an instance. I guess most people think that SomeClass.somemethod() is for classmethods... but static methods do not need self nor cls.

Comment: While @PM2Ring actually had the same answer, i mark this answer for putting an example

Comment: Arguably you never NEED a class. You could always just use a bunch of modules and closures! You'd use a class with all static methods for isolated scope and namespace without having to make a new module. This is especially useful in the case where you want everything isolated to a single file, and you have several very similar structures, e.g., 3 distinct entities with CRUD operations in a basic CLI app. @DevLounge

Answer (score 1):

Described case is too general to give the exact recipe. Relying on just your sample regular functions looks better here rather than decorator's and class complexity.

```
def somemethod():
   pass

def somemethod2():
   pass

def somemethod3():
   pass
```